# How to set up a svelte-carousel in modal pop-up

Tags: modal-dialog, popup, carousel, svelte, svelte-3

Sorry for the newbie question: I have a svelte website that was built for me, and I'm trying to tweak it to include a carousel in a modal pop-up. So my knowledge is limited and I am trying to get by.

However, when I run dev and the modal pop-up displays, it flickers:[image: screen cap showing carousel modal flickering]

I have followed [this tutorial](https://cloudinary.com/blog/how-to-create-a-carousel-in-3-ways-in-svelte) to build up a simple carousel on a page of the website and it works fine.I have also built a modal pop-up, the original version of which simply contained images and text. I deleted the images and text, and wanted to have the carousel display there instead.

In `<script>`, I include:

```
import ModalCarousel from '$lib/ui/ModalCarousel.svelte'; //modal pop-up for the carousel
import Carousel from '$lib/ui/carousels/SvelteCarousel.svelte'; //carousel itself
```

And later in the page's code (just under the first modal window, which I have not removed), I include:

```
<ModalCarousel bind:showModal>
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="content">
            <Carousel />
        </div>
    </div>
</ModalCarousel>
```

As indicated on the [repo of svelte-carousel](https://github.com/vadimkorr/svelte-carousel), I did install svelte-carousel as a dev dependency but could not do the following steps. (I got an error message when I ran dev telling me that I could not include `export default defineConfig({` in vite.config.js because I already had `export default config;` in it, and when I removed that, I got an error message about the `vite: {` element added to svelte.config.js).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Phil

Comment: Any ideas? Would be helpful.